# Efficients method for finding a zero of a multilinear complex polynomial in an specified region

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials, na.numerical-analysis

Let P be a given multilinear polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[z_1,\dots,z_n]$ and $D\subset \mathbb{C}$ be a given disc in the complex plane. Does there exist an efficient method for checking that $P$ has a zero in $D^n$ or not?

(A polynomial is called multilinear if its linear in each of its variables separately, for example $P(x,y)=xy-x+y+1$ is multilinear.)

Comment: What do you mean by efficient? And how are the coefficients of $P$ presented?

Comment: @MattF. The value of $n$ in my intended application is around ten and I have the value of all of coefficients. I want to have a method that can be implemented in a personal computer.

Comment: So you have the coefficients accurate to $10^{-7}$, and you are looking for a solution with $|P|<10^{-7}n$, or something like that?

Comment: @MattF. Usually it is $10^{-15}$ nowadays, but the problem seems rather hopeless even for $n=3$. I mean, there are good algorithms that can find a root *most of the time* (in which case one is sure that it exists) but I do not see any good algorithm that could *guarantee* that the root does not exist if it is the case. The problem is rather intriguing though. Its real analogue is simple because the full image is just an interval but in the complex case you may have quite fancy pictures...

Comment: @MattF. Yes, but I'm more interested to know whether there exits a root in the determined disc or not, the value of that root is not important.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the disk $D \in \mathbb{C}$ is the ball $B(z_0,r)$ with center $z_0$ and radius $r>0$. By the transformation
$$\zeta_k~=~ \frac{z_k-z_0}{r},~~k\in[n]~=~\{1,\ldots,n\},$$
the zeros of the multilinear polynomial  $P(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$ on $D^n$ correspond to the zeros of the
multilinear polynomial   $Q(\zeta_1,\ldots,\zeta_n)$ on   $B(0,1)^n$, and the coefficients $q_{I}$ for $I\in2^{[n]}$ are easy to calculate in terms of the  coefficients $p_{I}$ of $P$.
It is now evident that a necessary condition for the existence of a  zero  of $Q$ in $B(0,1)^n$ is
$$  \sum \limits_{I\in 2^{[n]}\backslash \emptyset}  |q_I|  ~\geq~|q_\emptyset|.$$
Unfortunately this is far from being a sufficient condition for large $n$. Because $Q$ generically has $2^n$ coefficients, but is controlled by only $n$ variables the non-constant terms heuristically perform a random walk in the complex plane. The maximal stepsize is achieved if all $|\zeta_k|=1$ and for equal $|q_{I}|=s$ the distance traveled will be
$2^{n/2}\,s$. For this to be 1 requires  $s=2^{-n/2}$, or
$$  \sum \limits_{I\in 2^{[n]}\backslash \emptyset} \frac{|q_I|}{|q_\emptyset|} ~\geq~2^{n/2}.$$
Probably for a sufficiently large right hand side of the given order of magnitude continuity and control over $n$ variables suffices to guarantee a solution. For right hand sides   between 1 and  $2^{n/2}$ solutions are unlikely, and  probably difficult to find if they exist.